# Netbeans Facelets code completion

Tags: java, jsf, netbeans, autocomplete, facelets

Does anyone know how one can enable the code completion for xhtml (facelets) files in Netbeans (6.7.1)?
According to some information I found on Google it is a known issue that there is no code completion for xml namespaces as used in the xhtml files, but that should be resolved by installing the netbeans facelets support module.
But even with this facelets support module, code completion for f, h, ui tags is not working for xhtml files, though, it is working for old school jsp files with taglibs.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the 6.8 Milestone releases (beta later this month).  They support Facelets pretty well.

I haven't had much luck with Facelets in 6.7.x, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I am using NetBeans 6.7.1 and code completion for facelets is working. 
I started the project as a facelets project and not a JSF project.[when asked to choose fameworks, choose facelets + any other framework and leave JSF blank].
I hope this helps.